How to plot label correct for daily on intraday with pine script v5
Here is my code.
I wanna label days that met conditions and on daily timeframe it works fine and labels appear where it should be. the problem is when I go to lower timeframe, the labels with Bull bear candles (D.Bull) work like I expected which labels show on candles of the day when conditions have met. However, the labels of REJECTION (31%) are not working properly.
The code of both parts are identical to me, because I duplicate and I fix a bit. I tried to fix it but can't.
please help me.[daily timeframe and 4h timeframe](https://i.sstatic.net/Yj3QR7ix.png)
[daily_open, daily_low, daily_high, daily_close] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [open, low, high, close])

///WICk////
// Calculate the upper and lower wicks
upperWick = daily_high - math.max(daily_open, daily_close)
lowerWick = math.min(daily_open, daily_close) - daily_low

// Calculate the percentages of the upper and lower wicks
upperWickPercentage = math.floor((upperWick / (daily_high - daily_low)) * 100)
lowerWickPercentage = math.floor((lowerWick / (daily_high - daily_low)) * 100)

//
// BULL bear candles
var label[] labels = array.new<label>()
var max_labels = 2

// Function to create a label and manage the array size
create_label(price, txt, y_location, color, text_color, style) =>
    new_label = label.new(bar_index, price, txt, yloc = y_location, color = color, textcolor = text_color, style = style, size = size.small)
    array.push(labels, new_label)
    
    // If array size exceeds max_labels, delete the oldest label
    if array.size(labels) > max_labels
        old_label = array.shift(labels)
        label.delete(old_label)

//
if lowerWickPercentage < 10 and daily_close < daily_open and lowerWick < 2 * math.max(daily_open, daily_close)
    create_label(high, "D.Bear", yloc.abovebar, color.red, color.black, label.style_label_down)


if upperWickPercentage < 10 and daily_close > daily_open and upperWick < 2 * math.max(daily_open, daily_close)
    create_label(low, "D.Bull", yloc.belowbar, color.blue, color.white, label.style_label_up)    

//
///REJECTION

var label[] labels1 = array.new<label>()
var max_labels1 = 3
create_label1(price, txt, y_location, color, text_color, style) =>
    new_label1 = label.new(bar_index, price, txt, yloc = y_location, color = color, textcolor = text_color, style = style, size = size.small)
    array.push(labels1, new_label1)
    // If array size exceeds max_labels, delete the oldest label
    if array.size(labels1) > max_labels1
        old_label1 = array.shift(labels1)
        label.delete(old_label1)

// Conditions to show the labels
if (upperWickPercentage >= 30 and upperWickPercentage > lowerWickPercentage) and daily_high > daily_close
    create_label1(high, str.tostring(upperWickPercentage) + "%", yloc.abovebar, color.red, color.black, label.style_label_down)  
if (lowerWickPercentage >= 30 and upperWickPercentage < lowerWickPercentage) and daily_low < daily_close
    create_label1(low, str.tostring(lowerWickPercentage) + "%", yloc.belowbar, color.blue, color.white, label.style_label_up)    



I hope someone can help me. I am quite new with coding.
Thank for your time
